# Does the identity $x/dx=1/d(ln(x))$ generalize to multidimensional calculus?

Tags: calculus, proof-explanation, vector-analysis

I know that if
$\int(\frac{1}{x}dx) =ln(x) $, then
$\frac{1}{d(ln⁡(x))}=\frac{x}{dx}$

My first instinct is to just replace every differential operator with a nabla, but how do I work through this to determine if this rule- or any for that matter -is still true in multiple dimensions, i.e., that $\frac{1}{\nabla(ln⁡(x))}=\frac{x}{\nabla(x)}$ where x is now a *vector* rather than a *scalar*?

Comment: What do you mean by $\frac{x}{dx}$?

Comment: By saying that $d(ln(x))=\frac{1}{x}dx$, then we may rearrange this to be $\frac{x}{dx}=\frac{1}{d(ln(x))}$

Comment: What does it mean to divide by $dx$? It's not a number or a function.

Comment: The relationship doesn't make physical sense unless arranged as it was initially in my above comment, but I had it this way originally as it was in the form necessary to substitute into another expression I hope to use in my research. I can restate the problem as $d(ln(x))\cdot x=dx$ if that will help convey what I am asking.

Comment: In one dimension you have $d(\ln(x)) = \dfrac{1}{x}dx$. If $x$ is a vector, what do you mean by $\ln(x)$?